# sql to join 2 tables with same foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, they both have a foreign key to a third table, how can I link these two tables together by using the foreign key, note that the foreign key is unique within a table.

```
SELECT A.id, B.id
FROM A, B
WHERE A.c_id = B.c_id;
```

Above is what i came up with, but it doesn't work as it return only 1 record.

Comment: Your given code should work. What makes you think there should be more than one record?

Comment: never mind, i forgot to use it on new data. someone should close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your way works for me. Here's an SQL Fiddle showing it working, with your exact code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10b06/1

Perhaps you're only getting one record returned because there only is one non-null `c_id` that appears in both table A and table B.

I suggest doing `SELECT DISTINCT c_id FROM A` and `SELECT DISTINCT c_id FROM B`, then looking at the lists by eye. I expect you'll find that there is only one value that appears in both results set (the one that you're currently getting returned).

Comment: You're right, the OP's SQL should work.